# Rotating a banner on hover causes it to spasm

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have an image on my website. When I hover over it I want it to do a 360 spin animation.

I'm currently doing so in CSS:-

```
.img-responsive:hover {
transition-duration: 2s;
transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

However, when the user hovers at the edge of the image, the image rotates and is no longer being hovered over at the edge causing the image to "spasm".

How can I achieve a proper looking and stable rotation? JavaScript would work too.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by adding small delay to your transition

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/GLR2g/1/)**

```
.img-responsive:hover {
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transform:rotate(360deg);
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
```

### Update:

If you can use `animation`, You can do this

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/GLR2g/2/)**

```
.img-responsive {
  animation: rotateme;
}

.img-responsive:hover {
  animation: rotateme 5s; 
}
```

Comment: That still causes it to fail the complete transition and slightly spasm though. Is there a way that I can make it complete the entire transition even if the user leaves the hover?

Comment: when I tried the "updated demo" in firefox it still "spasms" around the edges, but does not respond to hovering any second time (without reloading), seems a browser specific issue though, because both demos look fine in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image *bigger* when hovered, so that it's difficult that the user accidentally *unhovers*

if there is no padding or margin, set

```
.img-responsive:hover {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    padding: 50px;
    margin: -50px;
}
```

Increasing the padding to 50px makes sure that the mouse is still on it. Changing the margin in the same amount, but in opposite sense makes it  stay at the same location.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/GLR2g/1/)

Comment: true, this makes it harder to `unhover` but it only took me 3 tries to get it to spasm again :(